# "llvm-g++: command not found" while building BitCoin

Tags: macos, gcc, llvm, bitcoin

I was following [this](http://andarazoroflove.org/how-to-create-alt-coin-scrypt-clones-for-fun-and-profit-bitcoin-litecoin-secrets-exposed/) guide:

When I ran:

`make -f makefile.osx USE_UPNP=-`

here is what I got in the terminal:

```
/bin/sh ../share/genbuild.sh obj/build.h
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
llvm-g++ -c -g -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter  -DMAC_OSX -DMSG_NOSIGNAL=0 -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -DUSE_IPV6 -DUSE_UPNP=- -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -I"/Users/Bob/mycoin/src" -I"/Users/Bob/mycoin/src"/obj -I"/opt/local/include" -I"/opt/local/include/db48" -MMD -MF obj/version.d -o obj/version.o version.cpp
/bin/sh: llvm-g++: command not found
make: *** [obj/version.o] Error 127
```

Comment: one upvote for asking curious question..

Comment: Try the following link.. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/ it discusses all about bitcoins and its related things alone.

Answer (score 2):

Since Xcode 5 doesn't ship with `llvm-g++` anymore, you need to install it manually. One of the possible ways is to install command-line tools.

Another option is to just set `CXX` to `g++` in `makefile.osx`.